# Unhandled exception type IOException while getting an output from a text file using method

Tags: java, exception, io, compiler-errors

Below is my code, where I get a specific line from an output file. It gives me above error. Can some please help me as I new to this.

```
private final static String ThirdDeviceName=iPhone();



    public static String iPhone() throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("output.txt"));
          String str;
          int start = 0;
         int end = 0;
          int count = 0;

          while((str = br.readLine())!= null)
          {          
             StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str," ");
             count++;
             System.out.println(st.nextToken());      
          }
          br.close();
        return str;

    }
```

Comment: What does the stackTrace say?

Comment: It's `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("output.txt")));`.

Comment: @ VatsalSura That actually shouldn't matter. You can pass a File or a path to FileReader, it works either way.

Comment: @Mark Ohh... sorry I din't knew that.

Comment: @TheLostMind This is a compilation error. No stack trace.

Comment: Your `iPhone()` method throws an `IOException`, so you cannot use it in an initializer, which can't throw `IOExceptions` or any other checked exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Your method throws an IOException but you don't catch it anywhere. So it's unhandled. You can't use that method for a constant if it throws an exception.

Use a try-catch block instead of rethrowing the exception in your method or use a non final attribute that you set inside of a method where you can do the try-catch block.

Comment: Thank u will try that

Answer (score 1):

You still need to handle exception when you assign them to static fields.
One way of doing that would be:

```
private final static String ThirdDeviceName;

static {
   try {
     ThirdDeviceName=iPhone();

   } catch (IOException e){
     throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
}
```

But it would be a better approach to handle the exception in the `iPhone()` method.